# Decimal numbers on DevExpress XtraGrid cells

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, decimal-point

I have a DevExpress XtraGrid control in which I wanna put a decimal number in one of the cells, but when I try to jump from a cell to another it just not let me, unless I change again the value of the number to a integer.
I have modified the properties from design like this:

[[image: Image of designer]]

and nothing happened, also in the Form.Load event I set this property programmatically but it seems that just don't work.

```
colnBase.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric
colnBase.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "{0:N4}"
```

I have checked the DevExpress forums but I can't find an answer, it's my first question in here, so if any of you guys can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: So the format is working it just wants you to enter an integer with no decimal places if you try to leave the cell this number is in?  Are you using any type of mask for input?

Comment: No, all I've configured is just the DisplayFormat, but when I try to leave the cell with a decimal on it, it just don let me. My datatable has the same data type as the designer so thats not the problem.

Comment: Does: `colnBase.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom
colnBase.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "n4"` work?  I use this in a much older version of DevExpress and seems to work fine.

Comment: I tried and don't work either.

Comment: Might be a bug then.  As I also see it is used as a solution for their own developers in older support posts.

Comment: I'll just keep looking, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the "problem", the bug was that I was charging data from a View and all products records returned as 0

```
select 0 as data1, 0 as data2 from Table
```

But it seems that SQL returned the number as Integer and I couldn't be able to modificate the value in the XtraGrid even when it was declared as Decimal or Numeric in the DataTable and the XtraGrid.

I fixed it like this:

```
select convert(decimal(18,4),0) as data1, convert(decimal(18,4),0) as Data2 from Table
```

Thanks guys for answering and I hope someone else benefits from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong type of values in your underlying data source. The values in your `nBase` field must be one of the floating-point number type like `Single`, `Double`, `Decimal` etc.
Here is example:

```
Dim table = New DataTable()

table.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
table.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Single)) '<= If you change the type to Int32
' then you will not be able to write floating-point number into your cell

table.Rows.Add(0, 0)
table.Rows.Add(1, 1.1)

gridControl.DataSource = table

gridView1.PopulateColumns()

Dim displayFormat = gridView1.Columns("Value").DisplayFormat
displayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric
displayFormat.FormatString = "{0:N4}"
```

Comment: The system data type in the dataset is Decimal as the Grid.

Comment: @MartinOmarUriasLópez So, according to your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36414783/1805640), there are was `Int32` values in your underlying data source (`DataTable` in your case).

Comment: Yes but I couldn't figure it out at the time because in my design dataset I had have set the value as Decimal, and my primitive thoughts were that the DS will cast the value as Decimal because it was already declared so in the DS.